# How to organize Java Business object classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-access-layer

I am writing a web service and one of the operation in service is `getShortURL(String longURL)`. In this method I first check whether `longURL` exists in database, if yes, return it otherwise create a `shortURL`, insert it in database and return to client.

My confusion is how to organize and name my classes. Apart from the web service class, right now I have 3 classes:

1. `URLData`: It just has URL attributes and getters and setters.
2. `MongoDB`: It connects to database(right now connection attributes are hard-coded in it), inserts in database, and retrieves raw string from database.
3. `MongoDBUtil`: This class has again `insert(URLData)` method, it calls `MongoDB.insert()` to insert into database. Also has `retrieveURLData` which in turn calls `MongoDB` equivalent method to do the actual job.

Web service method sets `URLData` setters and calls `MongoDBUtil.retrieve` or `insert`.

1. I am thinking that `URLData` class should be named `URLDataBusinessObject` and along with setters and getters it can have insert, update and delete methods.
2. `MongoDBUtil` can be renamed to UrlDAO and it can have different kinds of retrieve methods.
3. `MongoDB` is more kinda Select query class, not sure how to design and name it.

Please advise

Comment: It's a simple service and best modeled in a simple way imo.  There's nothing wrong with your implementation.

Comment: agree it works but its a learning step for me and I want to do it the best way. I am looking people's thought about my proposed design and name changes and their own tips

Comment: I've added an answer containing some mongo specific advice

Answer (score 2):

1. URLData is fine. Don't bloat your class name with long irrelevant words. If you want to make clear that this is a business object, create a package like com.yourcompany.yourproject.bo for example, then put your URLData class in there.
2. Yes, UrlDAO is more specific than MongoDBUtil. You can create a com.yourcompany.yourproject.dao package for it.
3. Looks fine for me. However if you use some kind of framework (e.g. Spring) you don't have to create your own class to hold the database connection configurations.

I suggest you google for some tutorial on the topic, you will learn both how to use the technology and how to name/orginize your classes.

Comment: Posted question after googling. Appreciate if you can provide some links

Answer (score 1):

This question might be suited more for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Nevertheless: yes, I would change the naming.

1) `URLDataBusinessObject` No, never. You're adding 14 characters to a classname without adding any value. `URLData` was just fine.

2) You should change the naming of your DAO classes to be non-DB specific, unless you explicitly have an architecture aiming at multiple databases and the DB-specific classes perform DB-specific tasks.

I'm assuming this isn't the case and thus you should give it a more general name.
`Persistence` can be just fine, `DAO` as well, anything that shows the intended usage without going into specifics is eligible.

3) `MongoDBUtil` is your interface to the persistence layer, it's not a utility class in heart and soul. What's the purpose of this class? If all you do is chain the method call to `MongoDB` you might as well drop it and go straight to the latter.

Comment: What do you think about URLData class containing insert, delete methods

Comment: @Learner this would be an implementation of the "Active Record" pattern, which has its pros and cons. Just google the pattern name and see if it fits. There's no such thing as a general best practice.

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple layered design build interfaces for all the persistence specific operations and interfaces for all the domain objects.  Then code against those rather than their concrete implementations.  That way it's easy to swap out a mongo persistence layer for a different one, functionality is organised so that others can easily understand it and can also test against interfaces rather than concrete implementations.  You'd have something like:

1. URLData interface
2. URLDataDTO class (used in the business layer)
3. Persistence interface
4. MongoPersistence class (used in the persistence layer)

My current project does something similar and also works with Mongo.  The persistence layer interface has methods like "void put(URLData)".  When called the Mongo implementation constructs a new MongoURLData from the URLData passed in, extracts the DBObject then persists it.  Methods like "URLData get(String id);" work the other way around.  The Mongolayer queries the database and creates new URLDataDTO objects from Mongo DBObjects.  The web service is then responsible for serialising/deserialising DTO objects that are sent to or received from client applications.

My Mongo Domain objects all inherit from something this:

```
public abstract class MongoDO<T extends Object> {

DBObject dbobject = null;

public MongoDO(T dto) {
    this.dbobject = new BasicDBObject();
};

public MongoDO(DBObject obj) {
    this.setDBObject(obj);
};

public abstract T toDTO() throws StorageException;

public DBObject getDBObject() {
    return dbobject;
}

public void setDBObject(DBObject obj) {
    this.dbobject = obj;
}

public ObjectId getIdObject() {
    return (ObjectId) this.getDBObject().get("_id");
}

public void setIdObject(ObjectId id) {
    this.getDBObject().put("_id", id);
}

protected String getField(String field) {
    if (dbobject.containsField(field) && dbobject.get(field) !=null) {
        return dbobject.get(field).toString();
    } else
        return null;
}

protected void setField(String field, String value) {
    dbobject.put(field, value);
}

}
```

An example `Mongo` implementation would be:

```
public class MongoURLData extends MongoDO<URLData> implements URLData {
    private static final String FIELD_SHORT_URL = "surl";

    public String getShortUrl() {
        return getField(FIELD_SHORT_URL);
    }

    public void setShortUrl(String shortUrl) {
        setField(FIELD_SHORT_URL, shortUrl);
    }

    public URLData toDTO(){
        URLDataDTO dto = new URLDataDTO();
        dto.setShortURL(getShortURL);
        return dto;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm all for following SOLID principles and decoupled code. But if the solution is more complicated than the problem you're trying to solve you're perhaps doing something wrong.

Comment: He asked because he wanted to learn.  I'm not saying he should do this for a single class.  Also, this is a fairly simple implementation that works great - you create very simple entities that easily transform themselves non-mongo specific version and visa versa.